# What is this GPUCache folder that suddenly appears in the home directory?

Tags: home-directory

[image]

This folder has been popping up even when I was still in 18.04. I've deleted it before and at random times it just appears again. I've tried hiding it but another folder that's not hidden appears. What is it and is there a way to get rid of it or at least hide from the home directory?

Comment: i am not sure if you can hide it, but this is created by chrome/chromium browser

Comment: Thanks. I don't have chrome or chromium, so it must from Brave.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can hide it, but this is created by chrome/chromium browser, or electron apps.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wu is right. This is the cache created by Chrome/Chromium ([reference](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-13532)).

You can try to disable the cache according to [this article](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache):

> If you want to completely disable the Google Chrome cache, the setting is hidden in the developer options. Here’s how to access it in the Windows, OS X, and Linux versions. 
> Select the “Menu” button in the upper-right corner, then select “More tools” > “Developer tools“. You can also get to this screen by pressing Ctrl + Shift + I for Windows and Linux or Command + Option + I for Mac OS X.
> The Dev Tools window appears. Select “Network“,
> Check the “Disable cache” box.

However, this will mean that you will have to keep the developer options open.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, add a `.hidden` file in your profile root and put the names of the folders you want to hide in a single line per item. You might have to show/hide (CTRL+H twice) the folders to see the effect or reboot.